# Parent death is not killing child proess in C program Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, kill, orphan

See the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
                while(1);
        }
        else
        {
                while(1);
        }
}
```

Run this code from terminal 1:

Go to terminal 2, and check processes on terminal 1:

```
hduser@pc4:~$ ps -ft /dev/pts/1
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
hduser    3824  3505  0 17:20 pts/26   00:00:00 bash
hduser    4007  3824 21 17:33 pts/26   00:00:01 ./a.out
hduser    4008  4007 22 17:33 pts/26   00:00:02 ./a.out
hduser@pc4:~$
```

Two a.outs running here. Now kill the parent 4007.

```
hduser@pc4:~$ kill -9 4007
hduser@pc4:~$ ps -ft /dev/pts/26
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
hduser    3824  3505  0 17:20 pts/26   00:00:00 bash
hduser    4008  2077 24 17:33 pts/26   00:00:29 ./a.out
hduser@pc4:~$
```

Note 4008 is still running and it is now child of 2077(init --user).

My Doubt is:

1. Why child is not killed by parent before parents death?
2. Normally if we run any process from terminal(bash) without "nohup", and kill bash then child of bash is killed. How to implement this behaviour in our C program?
3. I thought default behaviour is that parent kills its child before death, and we have to call wait() to overcome this behaviour. But i was wrong. Then what is purpose of wait()?

I am using Ubuntu 14 with 3.13.0-52-generic kernel.

Comment: In linux the child process is not killed when the parent dies.

Comment: Why *should* the child process be killed when the parent exits? That kind of defeats the purpose of isolated and independent processes.

Comment: Make the child process daemon otherwise it will be adopted by init process after its parent live ends.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux / UNIX system, a process does not die unless it either exits or is explicitly killed by some other process.

What the `wait` system call does is suspend the process until one of its child processes dies.  You can also call `waitpid`, which waits for a specific child process to die.

If a process has a controlling terminal and the terminal quits, any process under that controlling terminal is killed by the OS.  You can use the `setsid` system call to detach a process from its controlling terminal so that it can live in the background even after the user logs out.

Comment: Not killed, sent a `SIGHUP`. This is why `nohup` works in those cases.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void main()
{
        int pid=fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
                execlp("gedit","gedit",NULL);
        }
        else
        {
                //wait();       
        }
}
kill -9 pid of a.out -> Only a.out killed not gedit

Comment: #include<stdio.h> #include<unistd.h> void main() { int pid=fork(); if(pid==0) { execlp("gedit","gedit",NULL); } else { //wait(); } } kill -9 pid of a.out -> Only a.out killed not gedit . For ctrl+c -> both killed. If we close terminal both are killed. For normal termination of a.out without wait(), only a.out killed.  What is happening exactly?

Comment: kill -9 kills only the specified process.  When you press ctrl-c, a SIGINT is sent to all processes in that controlling terminal. When a terminal closes, same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In linux the child process is not killed when the parent dies.

You can write a signal handler for the parent and in that signal handler you can call APIs to kill the child process.

Wait system call is invoked from the parent process to suspend it until one of its child terminates. Otherwise the child will become a zombie process.